# How to set local IP when originating TCP/IP connections?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

Using Linux and glibc, when originating a TCP/IP connection (calling connect() on a socket), how can I choose explicitly from which of my IP local adresses I want to originate that connection, providing I have more than one interface (with different IPs) from where I can reach the remote host?

Is it possible to do so, or it is always up to the operating system IP stack to chose the route automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind to a specific address instead of `0.0.0.0` or `::`.

Comment: But binding requires a port. What should be set as the port?

Comment: It can be set to an open port on the client side.

Comment: You can use port 0. It means any available port (picked by the kernel).

Comment: Similarly, one can bind to [::]:12345 if you need a specific port, but don't care about the address. (Great stuff that!)